# break country region report by location google ads api

Tags: google-ads-api

I've try to use google ads api to get the region report, which endpoint should i use to get this type of report?[image]

Answer (score 0):

for all you guys want to overcome this issue.
Google ads api provide api for get list of  [geo target](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/data/geotargets)
I'm using python, so this is the piece of codes:

```
    def get_geo_targets(self, customer_id):
    """
    get_geo_targets: return geo list targets
    Args:
        customer_id:

    Returns:

    """
    query_str = """
                SELECT geo_target_constant.id, geo_target_constant.name, 
                geo_target_constant.resource_name, geo_target_constant.country_code, 
                geo_target_constant.canonical_name, geo_target_constant.status, 
                geo_target_constant.target_type, geo_target_constant.parent_geo_target 
                FROM geo_target_constant where geo_target_constant.status !='REMOVAL_PLANNED'
            """

    ga_service = self._client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
    search_request = self._client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest")
    search_request.customer_id = customer_id
    search_request.query = query_str
    stream = ga_service.search_stream(search_request)

    result = []
    for batch in stream:
        for row in batch.results:
            geo_target_constant = row.geo_target_constant
            it = {
                'resource_name': geo_target_constant.resource_name,
                'id': geo_target_constant.id,
                'name': geo_target_constant.name,
                'country_code': geo_target_constant.country_code,
                'target_type': geo_target_constant.target_type,
                'status': geo_target_constant.status,
                # 'countrY_name': process_country(row.canonical_name),
                'canonical_name': geo_target_constant.canonical_name,
                'parent_geo_target': geo_target_constant.parent_geo_target}
            result.append(it)
    return result
```

the *resource_name* return from api, is the *segments.geo_target_region* return from *geographic_view*, just mapped it.